# Compare multiple files with ref file and print if it matches

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have multiple files which look like this:

```
b
alternate_ids rsid chromosome position alleleA alleleB index average_maximum_posterior_call info cohort_1_AA cohort_1_AB cohort_1_BB cohort_1_NULL all_AA all_AB all_BB all_NULL all_total all_maf missing_data_proportion frequentist_add_pvalue frequentist_add_info frequentist_add_beta_1 frequentist_add_se_1 comment
--- rs148087467 NA 60523 T G 1 0.999401 0.266624 7261.6 5.39417 0.00299072 0 7261.6 5.39417 0.00299072 0 7267 0.000371553 0 0.584342 0.247422 -0.473097 0.86481 NA
--- rs187110906 NA 60969 C A 2 0.995453 0.23508 7228.62 38.2204 0.138092 0.0169067 7228.62 38.2204 0.138092 0.0169067 7267 0.00264873 1.16325e-06 0.803757 0.281439 0.0754077 0
```

which I need to match with another file:

```
a
rs586178
rs79598313
rs72634501
rs191448950
rs9988450
rs11207995
```

In case `alternate_ids` and `a` matches, print matched row to a new file.

I have heard about

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};c[$1$2] > 0' file2 file1
```

but it compares only 2 files. Should I make a loop to run through all of files?

Comment: can you please specify how many files of type `a` and type `b` you might have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should parse the file `a` and if one of the lines is in file `b` , it will display the line :

```
for i in $(<a); do grep $i b; done
```

If you have one file of type `a` which contains the keys, and several of type `b`, you can just replace `b` with a variable looping on the filenames.

Comment: you're welcome. if you can give me some example of the `b` files i could give you a suggestion how to loop on them

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correcly, this should do what you want:

```
grep --no-filename --fixed-strings --file a b1 b2 b3 ... bN
```

or, with short options:

```
grep -h -F -f a b1 b2 b3 ... bN
```

It greps for fixed strings from file `a` in files `b1`, `b2`, `b3` etc.  The `-h` or `--no-filename` option suppresses output of each matching file's filename.

Comment: Thank you, but i have found out that grep is quite slow compared to awk which could execute the same..

Comment: I wouldn't be too sure about that - it depends on the implementation  versions and your locale .  In my testing (with a 1.6GB text file on a RAID-1 SSD), GNU `grep -F` & `grep -E`, and GNU `awk` all took around the same time (~6.8 seconds, with less than 0.2s variation between each of multiple runs) to search for the list of patterns in your `a` file.   `mawk` took about 2.9 seconds...but that's because `mawk` ignores the locale.  When I run them all again with `LC_ALL=C` (to override my `en_AU.utf8` locale), GNU `grep` wins with ~1.9 seconds, while `mawk` and GNU `awk` times remain unchanged.

Comment: In short, GNU grep is **really** hard to beat.  It's well known for being extremely fast.

Comment: sorry, my mistake...my 6.8s times for `grep` were because I had `grep` aliased to `grep --line-buffered`, which slows it down enormously.  Without that option,  GNU `grep` was taking only 1.8 - 2.0 seconds, with or without `LC_ALL=C`.  faster than mawk.